# How to create and call parameterised page-object classes

Tags: ruby, rspec, page-object-gem

I am using page-factory `visit`, `on`  methods to call page-object classes from spec file in ruby. I would like know how to parameterise page-object classes, passing parameters from spec file using page factory methods.

I want to log all steps information in page-object class. To do this, I created a log in spec file using the logger gem. I need to pass the log object as input parameter to page classes to capture data. Here is the code I am using to do this.

**spec file that calling page class:**

```
require './lib/pages/Test_page'
file="logs/uniusecase_#{@ncs_server['build_no']}_#{@ncs_server['test_type']}_#{time}.log"
$log=Logger.new(file)

describe 'testcase-1',:sanity do
     visit Testpage, using_params: {logger: $log} do |page|   
      end
end
```

**page-object class:**

```
class Testpage
 include PageObject 
 log = "<%=params[:logger]%>"
  def goto
   log ("test msg-1")
  end

  def testmethod() 
   log("test msg -2") 
  end 
end
```

I am getting `` "NameError:   undefined local variable or method `log' `` error message while execution. Could somebody help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The `:using_params` are stored in the class' `@merged_params` variable. You can get this variable by doing:

```
self.class.instance_variable_get(:@merged_params)
```

So your method would look something like:

```
def goto
  logger = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@merged_params)[:logger]
  logger("test msg-1")
end
```

However, if you are defining the logger in a global variable, it will already be available to the page object class (ie you do not need to pass it along). In other words, you could simply do:

```
def goto
  $log ("test msg-1")
end
```

Comment: glad to see your quick& detailed response. Both options are working . thanks you.